# How to Create a Download speed test with .NET

Tags: c#

I'd like to create a speed test to test the connection.

What I would like is a 15sec download which then gives me the average download speed.

Anyone knows how to create this? or has a better idea to make a speed test?

Answer (score 17):

As [publicENEMY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457030/publicenemy) says, the [kay.one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98970/kay-one)'s answer could give a wrong speed, because the HDD's speed can be lower than the network speed (for example: Google Gigabit Fiber is much faster than a 5200rpm HDD's average write speed)

This is an example code derived from the [kay.one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98970/kay-one)'s answer, but downloads the data content into a `System.Byte[]`, and therefore in memory.

Also i notice that after the very first download, the speed increases dramatically and jumps over the real network speed, because `System.Net.WebClient` uses the IE's download cache: for my requirements i only add the `t` querystring parameter, clearly unique for each request.

**EDIT**

[as.beaulieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6757551/as-beaulieu) finds an issue using `TimeSpan.Seconds` for the calculation, both for very fast and very slow downloads.

We just need to use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` instead.

```
Console.WriteLine("Downloading file....");

var watch = new Stopwatch();

byte[] data;
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    watch.Start();
    data = client.DownloadData("http://dl.google.com/googletalk/googletalk-setup.exe?t=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    watch.Stop();
}

var speed = data.LongLength / watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds; // instead of [Seconds] property

Console.WriteLine("Download duration: {0}", watch.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine("File size: {0}", data.Length.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0} bps ", speed.ToString("N0"));

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I'm having issues where my download is so fast that the few milliseconds in which it takes are rounded down to zero, and I get a divide by zero error at the 'var speed=...' line. How would I best correct that?

Comment: @as.beaulieu you right, and you show up another possible issue with that code: if the download takes over one minute, the `Second` gives a wrong value for our calculation.
I updated the code, just use `TotalSeconds` instead.

Comment: Whilst this has got a few upticks and is a reasonable solution, the problems with this are that the transfer speed increases over the first few seconds up to the max speed. The download file is also very small (1.5MB when I checked). A "better" way of doing a speed test would be to download a much much larger file (1Gb) and then start the stopwatch after 5 seconds, then wait 10 seconds before stopping it and seeing how much extra data has been downloaded.

Answer (score 16):

This sample will try to download googletalk, and then outputs details of the download.

ps. when trying to time and operation avoid using DateTime as they can cause problems or inacurecy, always use Stopwatch available at System.Diagnostics namespace.

```
const string tempfile = "tempfile.tmp";
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

Console.WriteLine("Downloading file....");

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://dl.google.com/googletalk/googletalk-setup.exe", tempfile);
sw.Stop();

System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(tempfile);
long speed = fileInfo.Length / sw.Elapsed.Seconds;

Console.WriteLine("Download duration: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine("File size: {0}", fileInfo.Length.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0} bps ", speed.ToString("N0"));

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: When trying to profile code at a very fine level avoid DateTime.Now().  But for something like a file download (which takes way longer than the precision of Now), it is just fine.

Comment: Or use 'QueryPerformanceFrequency' and 'QueryPerformanceCounter' as timer.

Comment: why go through the trouble of using performance counters or even DateTime.Now when Stopwatch is easy to use and built for this purpose.
it also makes your code easy to understand since its obvious that you are timing a function.

Comment: not only that this method does not use stopwatch(not perfect but the best available), this method write files to hdd. the problem from this is the maximum speed is bounded by hdd write speed, which is usually slow(+-300mbps).

Comment: @publicENEMY I just added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41426008/1401886) with an example based on this one, but that downloads the contents into an in-memory `System.Byte` array instead of a physical file.

Comment: In the speed calculation, use TotalSeconds, not Seconds (which is integer).

Answer (score 4):

- Use a known file size and trap how long it takes to download. (using two DateTime.now()s)

There is a library on CodeProject that I found. It is a couple of C# classes that let you monitor your network connections including upload and download speeds. [Link here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/networkmonitorl.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

how can a download file give you correct link speed.
what you get by downloading file is a great underestimate of the actual speed what you get.

What i think is you should do some udp sort of packet transfer and find the time required to receive it at the other end.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Publication**: [Understanding broadband speed measurements](https://www.measurementlab.net/publications/understanding-broadband-speed-measurements.pdf)

This may help someone looking to implement a speed test with the supporting theory.
The general algorithm can be seen here:

[Ookla Algorithm](https://github.com/miquels/speedtest/blob/master/doc/algorithm.md)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic dot net, the "My" class provide a function to download files, try to search for its alias in C#. Then create a timer counter and count seconds ellapsed since the download began.

Answer (score -1):

Use the code to check internet connection speed using C#:

```
private long bytesReceivedPrev = 0;
    private void CheckBandwidthUsage(DateTime now)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        long bytesReceived = 0;
        foreach (NetworkInterface inf in interfaces)
        {
            if (inf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel &&
                inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown && !inf.IsReceiveOnly)
            {
                bytesReceived += inf.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
            }
        }

        if (bytesReceivedPrev == 0)
        {
            bytesReceivedPrev = bytesReceived;
        }
        long bytesUsed = bytesReceived - bytesReceivedPrev;
        double kBytesUsed = bytesUsed / 1024;
        double mBytesUsed = kBytesUsed / 1024;
        internetUsage.Add(now, mBytesUsed);
        if (internetUsage.Count > 20)
        {
            internetUsage.Remove(internetUsage.Keys.First());
        }
        bytesReceivedPrev = bytesReceived;
    }

    private void CheckInternetSpeed(DateTime now)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri URL = new Uri("http://sixhoej.net/speedtest/1024kb.txt");
        double starttime = Environment.TickCount;
        client.DownloadFile(URL, Constants.GetAppDataPath() + "\\" + now.Ticks);
        double endtime = Environment.TickCount;

        double secs = Math.Floor(endtime - starttime) / 1000;

        double secs2 = Math.Round(secs, 0);

        double kbsec = Math.Round(1024 / secs);

        double mbsec = kbsec / 100;

        internetSpeed.Add(now, mbsec);
        if (internetSpeed.Count > 20)
        {
            internetSpeed.Remove(internetSpeed.Keys.First());
        }
        client.Dispose();
        try
        {
            // delete downloaded file
            System.IO.File.Delete(Constants.GetAppDataPath() + "\\" + now.Ticks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
        }
    }
```